# Can the URL from where DevContainers extension pull images be changed?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to add DevContainers to a project but I am unable to create the configuration using the existing `docker-compose.yml` file because of proxy issues. At work, we are behind a proxy and we need to prepend some information before being able to download external images. The error I am seeing says:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:!6) {
      errno: -60,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      port: 443
}
```

If I am getting this correct, the plugin is trying to download an image from `ghcr.io/devcontainers/templates/docker-existing-docker-compose:latest` but as I said we are restricted and need to prepend something (I will call it `proxywork` for security reasons) before the URL resulting in `proxywork/ghcr.io/devcontainers/templates/docker-existing-docker-compose:latest`.

Is there any way to change this setting within the plugin?